# Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6

Tags: gnome, firefox, google-chrome, gnome-shell-extension

When I try to download extensions on https://extensions.gnome.org/, this message appears:

> Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6. Probably you should upgrade native host connector or install plugins for missing APIs. Refer [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for instructions.

I have tried using both FireFox and Chrome. I'm new to Ubuntu so im not sure if this is a new problem or not. When I look for solutions it appears as this is a new bug.

How do I solve it?

Comment: Please also see the [forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2477062). Some of us have this error, but we can still install extensions, while others seem to have your problem. We don't know what's going on.

Comment: Update: This was [reported to Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chrome-gnome-shell/+bug/1983851). Please upvote (log in and see the green writing near the top left) if you agree with the report.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5622#note_1497615). Despite the message, installation of extensions will still work on Ubuntu that currently has Gnome Shell 42.2 , but the website is broken on e.g. Arch systems with Gnome Shell versions containing three components, e.g., 42.3.1.

So on Ubuntu, ignore the message for now. Ubuntu 22.04 users can use [Extension manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager) to install Gnome Shell extensions - it is actually the only way to easily install extensions because the website will not work with browsers installed as  snap. On older Ubuntu versions, the easier way to install the app would be to enable flatpak to install [the (official) flatpak version](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.mattjakeman.ExtensionManager).

Comment: I'm struggling to see that [issue #5622](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5622#note_1497615) fits this, because I get the same message on Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome 42.2, which doesn't have a second dot in the version number. Maybe I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 12):

See answer 1, under Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy, you can install [Extension manager](https://github.com/mjakeman/extension-manager) with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Comment: it not searching new extensions (2024-02-14)

Answer (score 0):

Like the first answer said, "Despite the message, installation of extensions will still work on Ubuntu that currently has Gnome Shell 42.2 , but the website is broken on e.g. Arch systems with Gnome Shell versions containing three components, e.g., 42.3.1."

One way to get around this is to disable the extension version validation.

On Ubuntu Systems you can run:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell disable-extension-version-validation true
```

And now you can visit the page and see the on/off toggle instead of incompatible.

Also make sure that you have also installed the [connector](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation?action=show&redirect=Projects%2FGnomeShellIntegrationForChrome%2FInstallation) beforehand.

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell
```