# not able to install gnome extensions via extensions.gnome.org

Tags: 20.04, gnome, google-chrome

I'm not able to install gnome extensions via extensions.gnome.org , I have chrome-gnome-shell package installed already and everything used to work fine till recently.Message in browser:

"Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6. Probably you should upgrade native host connector or install plugins for missing APIs. Refer documentation for instructions."

Is anyone having same issue, have an idea or know some workaround on this issue?

Comment: Please start with your OS & release details.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your native host connector do not support following APIs: v6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418937/your-native-host-connector-do-not-support-following-apis-v6)

Comment: Sorry I'm replying in lieu of the original author - the first link does not resolve the problem - 22.04 solutions are not available and older versions support are broken/abandoned by extensions.gnome.org.  I stopped reading the second when I saw "just install flatpak" and realised the answers weren't going to be serious.  The remainder are for 22.04 or not related (disabling extension version checking)

Answer (score 1):

Type the following commands into the Terminal.

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Then you can install the gnome extension manager by using the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-manager
```

Open Extension Manager(Jigsaw piece icon) then browse for extensions and install them.
You can access manually installed extensions by using the extensions software (Can be accessed through search)

This is an alternate solution. Instead of using host connector from gnome extensions you can try this method.

Comment: ii showing "unable to locate package for gnome-shell-extension-manager

Comment: FWIW this worked for me in 22.04 LTS

Comment: Extension manager is not available for 20.04 (original poster tagged as 20.04) - and I'm stuck there too.